# How might I go about making "Open" the default action for photos, instead of "Print" in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, printing, windows-11, context-menu

Recently I noticed that Windows 11 has "Print" as the top action in the context menu for image files, which makes no sense to me. I would like to set this back to "Open" as the top action so that I don't keep accidentally bringing up the print menu when I just want to open it.

[For more context, here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ6ez.jpg)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting the default application for the file extension to your desired application?  This is happening due to a registry key being associated with an incorrect application.

Comment: As "Ramhound" says, resetting the default app for that file type would fix the issue. Also, check out this thread at the Microsoft Answers community which says Adobe Reader may be implicated → [Photos keep opening in "print pictures" app instead of the - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/photos-keep-opening-in-print-pictures-app-instead/e0e46734-a791-439b-9347-0c746c64e2bc?page=3)

Comment: See, thats the weird thing. File associations are set to what they should be, as seen [here](https://imgur.com/0P94iP2), so that's not the problem here.

Comment: I also don't have Adobe Reader on my PC. Never have.

Comment: @arrowpuppet: Does resetting the Photos app (via PowerShell) help? The command to run is `Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Windows.Photos | Reset-AppxPackage`

Comment: Doesn't look like that changed anything

Comment: @arrowpuppet Can you download the "FileTypeDiag" utility (freeware), generate a file association report for PNG files, upload/link the file here?

Comment: [Here's the pastebin](https://pastebin.com/S5v047m2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Clipchamp shell extension is causing this issue. I could simulate the issue by installing the current version (v2.3.0.0) of the program.

[image]

Removing the Clipchamp shell extension fixes this problem. To do so, open an admin Command Prompt (run as administrator) and execute this command-line:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked" /v {8AB635F8-9A67-4698-AB99-784AD929F3B4}
```

Log off and log back in for the change to take effect. Alternately, you can restart the Explorer shell via Task Manager.

**References - Shell Extensions Issues:**

- [ClipChamp Shell Extension: Images Open in “Print Pictures” Instead of the Photos App](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/photos-open-print-pictures-instead-of-photos-app/)
- [Fix for Slow Right Click and Crashes Caused by Shell Extensions » Winhelponline](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-slow-right-click-crashes-shell-extensions/)
- [Sure, we do that: Context menu edition - The Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120516-00/?p=7613)
- [What goes wrong when you add "Copy To" to the context menu - The Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040202-00/?p=40773)
- [Has "Enqueue in Winamp" disappeared from your context menu? Uninstall clipchamp to get it back. : winamp](https://www.reddit.com/r/winamp/comments/udtugv/has_enqueue_in_winamp_disappeared_from_your/)